# Can't change Color Properties of a Custom Gradient Panel Class on Window Forms App

Tags: c#, winforms, linear-gradients

I have a custom gradient panel that I created by creating a new class under my Forms App. Everything was working fine until the color properties of the gradient panel cannot be changed by a button click on the App, but it was only able to change if you set the values at the very start of the program. But I wanted a feature where you could change the colors through a press of a button, here's my code for the custom gradient panel class:

```
namespace Color_
{
    public class GradientPane : Panel
    {
        
        public Color ColorRi { get; set; }
        public Color ColorLe { get; set; }

        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            LinearGradientBrush pane = new(this.ClientRectangle, this.ColorRi, this.ColorLe, 0F);
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;
            g.FillRectangle(pane, this.ClientRectangle);
            base.OnPaint(e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my code for the button press:

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pane.ColorRi = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B);
    button7.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B);
}

private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Pane.ColorLe = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B);
    button8.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B);
}
```

Neither of them work, but setting the colors on the very start of the program does:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    R = 255;
    G = 255;
    B = 255;
    Pane.ColorRi = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, 0);
    Pane.ColorLe = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, G, B);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: From the Property setter, you have to call `Invalidate()` -- You need to dispose of the Brush (better, declare it with an `using` statement) and what is this: `Graphics g = e.Graphics;` for?

Comment: @Jimi, Yeah the Invalidate() function was what I was missing! also the Graphics g declaration was for the next line of code; g.FillRectangle(pane, this.ClientRectangle);, Was it also not needed?

Comment: Not needed, just `e.Graphics.FillRectangle(...);`. It doesn't cause any *harm*, it's sometimes used to make `e.Graphics` *shorter*, but it has no other functionality -- It's important that you call `Invalidate()` from the setter because you want to see the color change also in the Visual Designer (sometimes, depending on various conditions, you also have to invalidate the Parent, also specifying the bounds of your Control)

Comment: ah oh yeah forgot about that, looks like I just slacked off a bit even if its just for one line of code haha, but yess I'll also take the second suggestion! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The issue is related to how the ***GradientPane*** control is repainted when the colors are updated. When the colors are set at the start of the program in the Form1 constructor, the control is painted with the specified colors. However, when the colors are changed using button clicks, the ***OnPaint*** method is not automatically called to repaint the control with the new colors.

To fix this issue, you need to explicitly trigger the repaint of the GradientPane control after updating the colors. You can do this by calling the ***Invalidate()*** method on the GradientPane control. This method tells the control to redraw itself, and the ***OnPaint*** method will be called with the updated colors.

Here's how you can update your button click event handlers to fix the issue:

```
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Pane.ColorRi = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B);
      button7.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B);
      Pane.Invalidate(); // Trigger repaint
        }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      Pane.ColorLe = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B);
      button8.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, R, G, B);
      Pane.Invalidate(); // Trigger repaint
        }
```

By calling ***Invalidate()*** after updating the colors, the ***GradientPane*** control will be repainted with the new colors, and you should see the changes take effect when you click the buttons.